# iPhone location scouting app that reads geo-location exif data

Tags: geotagging, iphone, locations, apps

Does anyone know of a iPhone/iOS app that helps with scouting or keeping a file of good locations?  The big caveat is that it should be able to read exif location data of photos previously taken that are in your library/film roll.

Of the apps I have found, they only record your present location. If you take a photo with the app, it is ok but if you import the photo from your iPhone library, it places the location of the photo as the place where you are when making the entry!

Comment: If the location is not recorded based on the photo location, I'd argue that's a bug. Or at least, a significant feature that should be added. Contact the developer of the app?

Comment: It seems it is common to most if not all the popular apps available. I guess I could contact them, just wondering if anyone here has already downloaded/bought an app with the functionality already implemented correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MapAPic Location Scout](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id519612179?pt=1020283&ct=so&mt=8) is good for remembering locations. After you add some locations, you can tag them, search, get directions, share/print as PDFs, and more.

UPDATE: As of June 2013, MapAPic can read geo-location exif data from images, and create new locations using that data!

Comment: It is a pity that it doesn't have this functionality. For me, it is almost useless as I take quick snaps with the built in camera app and go back to them, rather than fire up an app and have to create a location on the spot.  Here's hoping that you can implement it soon, or that someone else can!

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the fact that Map-A-Pic now reads geolocation data from images.

Comment: Only took a year or so!  Functionality is there, pity it is using Apple Maps instead of Google Maps

Comment: From a development point of view, it's a heckuvalot easier to use Apple Maps than Google Maps in iOS. And at this point (a few years after the previous comment) Apple Maps is actually getting pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

[Scout](http://www.makescout.com/) for iOS is pretty new and looks extremely good, especially compared to Map-A-Pic.

Comment: Can scout work WITHOUT logging in? I have no desired to be part of yet another social site. I just want to scout my own photos...

Answer (score 1):

Trey Ratcliff has an app, [Stuck on Earth](http://www.stuckonearthapp.com) that does the virtual scouting aspect of what you want. It uses location data from flickr to show you pictures on a large map. You can scroll around and find cool pics and spots.

As mentioned, the app [Scout](http://www.makescout.com/) does the second part quite well, so you can make a journal of places you want to remember for locations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want but the built in Photos app on iPhone can show you on a map all the locations of previously taken photos.  Just tap "Places" along the bottom navigation bar of the Photos app.  (On the right, next to Albums and Photo Stream).

Comment: thanks, but no it's isn't quite what I (or others I suspect) need for keeping a scouting database of interesting locations

Answer (score 0):

i know it's been 7 years but since there's no decent solution out there I built myself one for ios and i think is exactly what you want. It's called Spoto and you can add photos from your library, take ones with the camera, and explore the map for photos added by others. There's also a feed with curated locations and sun/moon times. And there are many more things to come.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spoto-photo-video-scouting/id1402237023

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app a few years ago that does some of this, Current Locations.

However, I usually just take a picture of the place with the Camera app. I then download the full photo from Photos and import into GraphicConverter to retrieve the lat/long data.

You could stay in Photos and put interesting place photos in their own folder. You can also select photos by place on a map with Photos.